# R tmap zoom misaligned grid

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, polygon, tmap

I'm trying to work with 20m x 20m resolution Corine landcover data for Finland
([CORINE maanpeite 2018, 20 m](https://www.syke.fi/fi-FI/Avoin_tieto/Paikkatietoaineistot/Ladattavat_paikkatietoaineistot#C)), which is in EPSG:3067 map projection. I also have the official Statistics Finland grid polygons at 250m x 250m resolution (also in EPSG:3067). Sorry, I don't think that the grid is freely available, but I've added the import information underneath.

```
library(sf)
library(rgdal)
# load corine
corine <- raster(x = "../Clc2018_FI20m.tif")
# check map projection
crs(corine) 
# load grid
grid.250 <- st_read("../T11_grd_e_250m.shp")
```

```
Reading layer `T11_grd_e_250m' from data source `..\T11_grd_e_250m.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Simple feature collection with 6262152 features and 7 fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 61500 ymin: 6605750 xmax: 733000 ymax: 7776500
projected CRS:  ETRS89 / TM35FIN(E,N)
```

I'm cropping both objects first:

```
# crop around Helsinki
e <- extent(362960,403020,6656040,6697640)
grid.250.cropped <- st_crop(grid.250, e)
corine.cropped <- crop(corine, e)
```

In QGIS they line up perfectly, but when I zoom in on `tmap`, I have a misaligned grid. I believe this might just be an optical error and not a real one. How can I check and/or fix this?
**Update:** A polygon created from the raster file aligns perfectly, so it seems to be indeed cosmetic (does not affect spatial stats, but is plotted wrong).

```
library(tmap)
tmap_mode("view")

tm_shape(corine.cropped) +
  tm_raster() +
tm_shape(grid.250.cropped) + 
  tm_polygons("GRIDCODE", alpha = .25)
```

[image: tmap]
[image: tmap_zoom]

Here's an example of the same data in QGIS. As you can see the raster lines up perfectly with the grid.

[image: QGIS]